# Login page database connection

Tags: php

I have created the code for login page in php. but i need to know whether the code is correct or not. it's not properly working. Even if I entered the correct user name and password, it says that, 'you are not a valid user.please try again'. how can I fix this??
The code is as follows;

```
<?php
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];

if ($uname) {
   $dhost="localhost";
   $dusername="locas";
   $dpassword="locas@learn";
   $db="locas";

   mysql_connect($dhost,$dusername,$dpassword) or die("cannot connect");
   mysql_select_db("$db")or die("cannot select db");

   echo "$uname<br>";
   $result=mysql_query("select user.fname,password.pwd from user,password where user.uid=password.uid and user.fname==$uname");           
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

   if ($row["fname"]==$uname && $row["pwd"]==$pwd) {
      echo"you are a valid user.";
   } else {
      echo" You are not a valid user.Please try agian.";
   }
};
?>
```

Comment: echo the query and execute it once and check whether it is working properly.

Comment: select user.fname,password.pwd from user,password where 
user.uid=password.uid and user.fname==$uname? Does that query work when you run it on MYSQL panel directly?

Comment: @user2981403: I don't think that `==` is required in mysql query

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues in your query...

1. `$uname` is string. You must quote it.
2. You are using `==`. You are mixing `PHP` and `mysql`. Use `=` instead.

Update your query...

```
$result=mysql_query("select user.fname,password.pwd from user,password where 
    user.uid=password.uid and user.fname='$uname'");
```

---

> you also need to use mysqli_* or PDO; mysql_* functions are
>   deprecated. On top of that, you have SQL injection vulnerability, so
>   please do not use this code in production!

Comment: @user3015967: you also need to use mysqli_* or PDO; mysql_* functions are deprecated.  On top of that, you have SQL injection vulnerability, so please do not use this code in production!

Answer (score 0):

If your query is correct which I am not sure if that will run fine, you should try the following;

```
$row=mysql_num_rows($result);


if ($row>0)
{
 echo"you are a valid user.";
}

else
{
 echo" You are not a valid user.Please try agian.";
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

```
select user.fname,password.pwd from user,password where 
user.uid=password.uid and user.fname==$uname
```

In the above query, try using `=` instead of `==`

Source : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

You should join the two tables by a common index. Something like this:

```
SELECT `user`.`fname`,`password`.`pwd` FROM `user`,
INNER JOIN `password` USING (`uid`)
WHERE user.fname='$uname' AND password.pwd = '$pwd'
```

Be sure to sanitize the username and password with mysql_real_escape_string! Also the password should be a private hash (md5 or sha-1).

After the query you simply check whether you get an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

try updating this:

```
$uname  = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '';
$pwd    = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : '';
```

and query to:

```
"SELECT user.fname, password.pwd FROM user,password WHERE user.uid = password.uid and user.fname ='".$uname."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use  `user.fname='".mysql_real_escape_string($uname)."'` instead of `user.fname==$uname`

```
    $dhost="localhost";
    $dusername="locas";
    $dpassword="locas@learn";
    $db="locas";        

        $link = mysql_connect($dhost, $dusername, $dpassword);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
        }

        // make foo the current db
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db($db, $link);
        if (!$db_selected) {
            die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
        }

       $result=mysql_query("select user.fname,password.pwd from user,password where user.uid=password.uid and user.fname='".mysql_real_escape_string($uname)."' ORDER BY uid ASC LIMIT 1 ");
```

Note: `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.